# Getting a value from my sql database in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I've been having a bit of trouble with this for a while, please can somebody shed some light onto this?

What's happening so far: When a button is clicked, a search statement occurs and an AJAX call is made and brings back a set of results (displayed as a table) these results coming from a table in mysql database called 'ticket. The values displayed from the ticket table are 'venue' 'date' 'time' 'tPrice'.
This 'tPrice' is a number which has been set i.e. 15/20/25 to represent the price of a ticket. This works and displays fine but I'm having a problem trying to get the value of the price of the ticket in Javascript, does anyone know how to refer to a number in a mysql table in JS?

What I'm wanting to do with this value is multiply it to the value of whatever number is selected from a drop-down menu. (this drop-down menu is also returned by AJAX as part of the  results of the user's search, this search result page is written in php and echoes the drop-down menu as a column within the results table)

What I have so far is this:

```
function quantityChange() {
//Select the value of the drop down list       
var quantity = $('.summary').html($('#showQuantity option:selected').val());
//get the value of the number from the tPrice column in 'ticket' table
var ticket = parseFloat($('#ticketprice').val());
//multiply them together
var total = quantity * ticket;
return (total);
```

After debugging in Firebug, it's giving me no errors but it's also not giving me any results...please, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

EDIT:
The php code:

```
$postCodeSQL = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE locationID IN (SELECT locationID FROM location WHERE postCode LIKE '$pcSearch') ";

  $postCoderesult = mysql_query($postCodeSQL) or die(mysql_error());

  while ($pcRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($postCoderesult)) {
    $venue = $pcRow['venue'];
    $ticketPrice = $pcRow['tPrice'];
    $date = $pcRow['date'];
    $time= $pcRow['time'];

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>$venue</td>\n";
    echo "<td id=\"ticketprice\">&pound$ticketPrice</td>\n";
    echo "<td >
         <select name =\"showQuantity\" id=\"showQuantity\" class =\"showQuantity\" onchange=\"quantityChange()\" >
                   <option value=\"1\">1</option>
           <option value=\"2\">2</option>
           <option value=\"3\">3</option>
           <option value=\"4\">4</option>
           <option value=\"5\">5</option>
         </select>
        </td>\n";
     echo "<td>$date</td>\n";
     echo "<td>$time</td>\n";
     echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you only have one "ticketprice" dropdown on the page? You're giving an ID in that selector there, so I'm hoping so...are you sure the value is getting populated in the drop down's options? You might right-click and inspect the element with Firebug just to be sure.

Comment: You don't need `$('.summary').html($('#showQuantity option:selected').val())`. `$('#showQuantity option:selected').val()` is enough.

Comment: What does Firebug show for the value of `quantity` and `ticket` just prior to calculating `total`?

Comment: The drop down does have an ID yes and I have manually entered the values for the options values (1 - 5) but the tPrice (from the database) is being generated in a while{ } loop in the php file

Comment: try: `alert(qanitity)` after defining the var and the same for ticket. What's the output of the alert messages?

Comment: @florian Margaine: the $('.summary') is added because Im wanting to get the value from the dropdown menu and display it in my 'summary' class.

Comment: @Ofir Baruch: When I do an alert(quantity) after defining the var, the response is [object Object]. What does this mean?

Comment: Notice that the ID of the SELECT isn't unique because it's in a loop , so you have the same ID for X SELECT ELEMENTS , that can cause problems.

Comment: Ah really? Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Would it be more sensible to use a SELECT class instead?

Comment: In addition, when I do an alert(quantity); is displays the selected option value...when I alert(ticket); it displays 'NaN'.

Comment: Oh! That's a big hint. Notice that in your HTML the value of the ticketprice isn't the value of the TD and there's a string attached to the price. Try following my answer (even just steps 4 and 5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (change the trigger function)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function quantityChange() {
//Select the value of the drop down list       
var quantity = $('#showQuantity option:selected').val();
//get the value of the number from the tPrice column in 'ticket' table
var ticket = parseFloat($('#ticketprice').val());
//multiply them together
var total = quantity * ticket;
//console.log(total);
//console.log(ticket);
//console.log(quantity);
return (total);
}

// Need a simple trigger
$('#showQuantity').change(function() {
        quantityChange();
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you Charles Weiss for your response, I have implemented these changes and Firefox tells me that quantityChange() is not defined?

Comment: check for mispelling between the function name when defining it to the function name when calling it.

Comment: Thank you, I shall do this. When I alert(ticket); its giving me 'NaN' (not a number) for some reason it won't recognise the value in my tPrice column as a number :/

Comment: @TimJohnstone: I took it for granted that there was only 1 select statement, and that you are running jQuery. You might need to use a "live" handler on the trigger to detect the ajax changes to the dom.

Answer (score 0):

As said , you have more than one element with the same ID.
So when you're writing a code to get the value by elemeny's id = troubles.
Try:

1.Change the next line:

```
onchange=\"quantityChange()\"
```

to:

```
onChange=\"quantityChange(this)\"
```

2.Change your function defining line to:

```
function quanitityChange(selElem){
```

3.change the next line:

```
var quantity = $('.summary').html($('#showQuantity option:selected').val());
```

to:

```
var quantity = parseFloat($(this).find(":selected").val());
```

4.Change:

```
echo "<td id=\"ticketprice\">&pound$ticketPrice</td>\n";
```

to:

```
echo "<td id=\"ticketprice\">&pound$ticketPrice<input type='hidden' id='ticketPriceHidden' value='".$ticketPrice."'></td>\n";
```

5.In your function again:

```
var ticket = parseFloat($(this).parent().find("input#ticketPriceHidden").val());
```

Works? What the output of quantity and ticket now?

Comment: Thank you dude. However the output for this is 'NaN'. I'm able to get the option value that the user selects but the major problem I'm having is getting the value of:

    $ticketPrice = $pcRow['tPrice'];
    echo "<td id=\"ticketprice\">&pound$ticketPrice</td>\n";

This is the value that is stored in my database and Im trying to make the function get this ['tPrice'] value and multiply it to the quantity variable.

Comment: Thank you, however I'm now getting 'NaN' for both the quantity and ticket when I alert() them. Would you like me to re-post the code I have now?

Comment: You should update your question with your current code and output.